# Can't create a new file under the project w/ XCode 6.4 beta under El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I'll create a new file while the group is selected, but the file gets created outside the project hierarchy.

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it done with this workaround:

- Create the Cocoa class
- ⌘-drag it into the project/folder I want (unchecking 'Copy items if needed' and selecting 'Create folder references')
- Delete the files that are outside the project by Right-Clicking, selecting 'Delete' and then 'Remove References'

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Swift File instead of cocoa class file.

Comment: this is true, but why can't we create cocoa class files?

Comment: @godmode It's a bug yet got fixed